# ADR Recording Software

Tags: adr, software, recording, beeps

I am new to ADR recording. I have a question specifically for beeps/streamers software:

I have seen on DVD extras that show the ADR recordings and I have noticed that their software is able to give beeps and streamers at each paragraph or new "cue" while it rolls on recording.

The software I have and use is ADR Studio Pro by Gallery. This software does not have the option of continuing to record and give streamers as it records.

Does anyone know of software that is able to send streamers as it records without having to stop to give the next cue?

The last actor I recorded asked for this and I looked unprofessional saying "Sorry, I can't do that with the software I have".

So what do they use on the big studio ADR stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Figure 53](http://figure53.com/streamers/) may work for your needs, although I have no experience with it.

[image: Figure 53]
<sub>(source: [figure53.com](http://figure53.com/streamers/images/screenshot.jpg))</sub>

The major ADR stages usually use a proprietary system designed exclusively for them.

Here's a little blurb about how [Doc Kane](http://studioservices.go.com/postproduction/adr_stage_b.html) at Disney runs his stage. And yet another article about how the excellent tech crew at Warner Bros developed a [mobile ADR studio](https://www.editorsguild.com/Magazine.cfm?ArticleID=813).

Comment: Great - thanks. How does one go about getting an apprenticeship in ADR?

Comment: If you're looking to make it into a career, I'd suggest an internship at either a small independent studio (non-union) or inquire at one of the studios about a real apprentice position (union). My feeling is you'll have much more success at the independent shops simply because it's easier to get in. Once you're there, learn everything you can from the top guy/girl about mics, gear, how to interact with talent and clients, etc. Good luck -

Answer (score 1):

I've only done ADR in small studios here in NYC, using Pro-Tools. Don't know about the streamers, but beeps just take a little prep-work before your session and pretty much every actor I've worked with is fine with just beeps (three beeps, one frame each, first 2 at 1k, 3rd at 2k).

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately it's the streamers the actor wanted and not the beeps. If it were the beeps It'd be as simple as copy/paste in Pro Tools. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

My studio is straight Pro-Tools, the beeps and streamers are generated using a Midi track.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. What software creates the streamers? That's brilliant. Obviously it will send a streamer as you continue to record, right? Like a long monologue that has many cues it will continue to send streamers as you record?